# Highcharts - how to add icons to a label

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm using highcarts to add a label to the centre of my pie chart. I'm using the labels config options but I want to add a label to the beginning of it as such:

[image]

I've tried multiple things, including the labelFormatter but nothing seem to work. Currently my code stands as:

```
labels: {
  items: [{
   useHTML: true, // Using HTML for label
    //html: "Transactions",
    html: '<img src="https://github.com/tobi-ajala/shell-exercise/blob/master/icons/card.png?raw=true"/>' + "Transactions", // Doesn't work!
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Arial,Roboto,Helvetica,sans-serif',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 14,
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      top: 140,
      left: 460
    }
  }]
},
```

Please see the JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tobitobetoby/1fqvzpdn/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`labels.items` doesn't seem to support images.

You can use `renderer` to create the label with the exact inner HTML that you pass as an argument. Notice that `useHTML` option (7th argument) is enabled. Then you can style it via CSS.

```
this.renderer.label("<div class='transactions'>
   <img src='https://github.com/tobi-ajala/shell-exercise/blob/master/icons/card.png?raw=true'/>
         Transactions</div>", 120, 125, null, null, null, true).add();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/p4nnxjq1/

API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.label

Comment: Do you know how to align the image and the text in the middle? verticalAlign: middle; doesn't seem to be working :S

Comment: The labels rendered via renderer have absolute position and their parent is the whole container - you need to use second (x) and third (y) arguments of renderer.label function to position them properly. Other solution would be to move the label code to the title and use useHTML the same way as I did in the answer. Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/p4nnxjq1/